# Social Connect for Visual Studio

Tags: app, placeholder

#### About

This app will post content to Stack Exchange websites from Visual Studio. It will also notify about activities in the account. Its an extension for Visual Studio. It is for everyone. It is for free. It uses Stack Exchange APIs & C#. We can post questions, answers and comments without going out of Visual Studio.

#### License

No License. Its free.

#### Download

[Social Connect](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a0e66019-060e-4951-b1b9-d6c475ffce1d)

#### Platform

Windows.

#### Contact

My Team. Email ids will be released shortly.

#### Code

C#. Code will be released soon on GitHub. Everybody can contribute.